# Gets results only when empty

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error, sql-injection

I have this sql statement that returns rows from a customer table.  The user has the option for searching with what ever they want to type in.  I had this working, until I tried to protect against sql injecting by using bindValue.  Now I can't get any results to return unless the user leaves the textbox blank.  Below is my code.

**Model**

```
function searchMyCusts($field, $query){          
    $data = null;
    $msg = null;
    $status = null;

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".CustomerFields::ID.",".CustomerFields::FirstName.",".CustomerFields::LastName.",".CustomerFields::PhoneNumber." FROM ".CustomerFields::TableName." WHERE '$field' LIKE :query");

    $sth->bindValue(':query', $query);

    if ($sth->execute()){
        $status = "success";
        $msg = "Customer entry successfully altered";            
        $data = $this->smartFetchAll($sth);


    }else{
        $status = "error";            
        $msg = "An error occurred. :".$sth->errorInfo()[2];
    }

    $jsonData = json_encode($this->buildResponseArray($status, $msg, $data));        
    return $jsonData;
}
```

In the prepare line at the end I have the values being passed in.  Like I said this was working until I attempted to bindValue the query variable.

I would appreciate any insight you may have.  Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: Please add the appropriate tag for the language you're using (PHP, etc.)

Comment: Can you post `echo $query` before you do prepare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how could it work before but first of all you need to change

```
" WHERE '$field' LIKE :query"
```

to

```
" WHERE $field LIKE :query"
```

or

```
" WHERE `$field` LIKE :query"
```

You can't use quotes around a column name because it becomes just a literal string which you compare with `:query` pattern. The query will work but you'll have no rows returned. Either nothing or back ticks.

Secondly `$query` should contain all necessary wildcard symbols prior to prepare. E.g.

```
$query = "%new%";
```

*It's not clear whether it's the case from your code*

Comment: Thank you peterm it turns out that was my issue.  It's always something little that never catches your eye.  Much thanks!